# How to include libssh2 to c project in visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio, ssh, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a simple c program that uses the libssh2 library.
for the installation (build+install) i used cmake-gui (i'm using windows 10 x64) with openSSL option is on and zlib is off.

i was trying different solution to include the library with the right dependencies but each time a different error message shows up. like:

when i include only the ssh2 library path `-I "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\libssh2\\include"  -L "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\libssh2\\lib" -lssh2`

error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\libssh2\lib/libssh2.a(openssl.c.obj):openssl.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to 'BN_bn2bin'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\libssh2\lib/libssh2.a(openssl.c.obj):openssl.c:(.rdata$.refptr.PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey[.refptr.PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey]+0x0): undefined reference to 'PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\libssh2\lib/libssh2.a(pem.c.obj):pem.c:(.text+0x6dd): undefined reference to 'EVP_DigestUpdate'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\libssh2\lib/libssh2.a(bcrypt_pbkdf.c.obj):bcrypt_pbkdf.c:(.text+0x3bb): undefined reference to 'EVP_DigestUpdate'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\libssh2\lib/libssh2.a(crypt.c.obj):crypt.c:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'

i didn't post all the error message but i notice those libraries in "()" are messing like crypt and openssl. so i tried to include them by add the path of the openSSL installation directory to the compiler arguement: `-I 'C:\Program Files (x86)\libssh2\include' -I C:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -L 'C:\Program Files (x86)\libssh2\lib' -L C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib -lssh2 -lws2_32 -lcrypto -lssl`
but it didn't work because he can't find those libraries:

> cannot find -lcrypto
>
> cannot find -lssl
>   the openSSL installation folder has the include folder with theesheaders files and the lib folder with .lib files (and i'm not sure 100% if the mingw64 can use those extension or it should be .a).

maybe this question was asked before but after couple of days searching i couldn't find a solution works for me. so sorry for the duplicate post.

this is my task file:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Build active file",
        "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-6.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-Wall",
            "-Wextra",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-I",
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\libssh2\\include",
            "-I",
            "C:\\OpenSSL-Win64\\include",
            "-L", 
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\libssh2\\lib",
            "-L",
            "C:\\OpenSSL-Win64\\lib",
            "-lssh2",
            "-lws2_32",
            "-lcrypto",
            "-lssl",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-6.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1\\mingw64\\bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Run active file",
        "command":".\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
    }
]
```

}

i'm not sure if you need the c_cpp_properites file:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.10586.0",
        "compilerPath": "\"C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe\"",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. i was missing the .dll files for the openSSL library. the dll files was in the root folder (openSSL folder) i had to copy them and post in the lib folder (openSSL/lib) and change the name from libcrypto-1_1-x64 to libcrypto-1_1-x64 and the same for ssl, i though i need the .a files of the openSSL and because i'm using windows the openSSL installed the .lib files not the .a and a lib file need dll, this what i understood. that's all, the task file i posted was correct. you read @Brecht Sanders answer for more informations.

Answer (score 2):

You always need to link with the dependancies of your application or shared library (which you did using `-lssh2`), but if you're doing a static build you also need to include the dependancies of the dependancies.

On Linux or when using MSYS2 on Windows you can get the actual link parameters using `pkg-config.exe`, like this:

```
pkg-config.exe --static --libs libssh2
```

which in my case returns:

```
-LD:/Prog/winlibs64-9.2.0-7.0.0/custombuilt/lib -lssh2 -lws2_32 -lssl -lcrypto -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcrypt32 -lz
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i already found the solution i just come here to post it. and about your answer, it's correct. i needed the dependencies of the dependency (ssh2). as i posted in my question i already did that, the problem was the missing dll and not the entire openSSL library. openSSL was installed without the .a files, only .lib but the folder was missing some dll where i found them in the folder root. i just had to copy and post them with changing the name to what i need.